# What does happen when using a vpn in the guest VM with NAT?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

If I have a host machine that doesn't use a VPN and I launch a guest VM and use a VPN inside it, what happens when using NAT networking mode?
From my understading in NAT mode the host acts like a router, so basically the host will navigate as usual while the guest will have created a tunnel from itself to the vpn server, so if watching traffic from the gateway I'll see a clear traffic and a tunneled one, correct? Does this exfiltrate data?
And from an external server POV, if I connect via the VM, I should only see the IP of the VPN and not the one of the gateway, right?

Comment: Yes this is a potential data exfiltration method, but any IT guy worth their water will quickly notice a long standing connection (or group of connections) with large amounts of data and failure of packet inspection to determine the nature of the data as in webpages, images, video, etc. They would also be able to easily lookup and match VPN or cloud service providers. In short it would raise some real red flags. Networks could easily be set up to log and/or deny access to such services.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this setup often enough in order to liberate the host from constraints
imposed by too-restrictive VPN servers, and everything should work as you said.

> the host will navigate as usual while the guest will have created a tunnel from itself to the vpn server, so if watching traffic from the gateway I'll see a clear traffic and a tunneled one, correct?

Correct.

> Does this exfiltrate data? And from an external server POV, if I connect via the VM, I should only see the IP of the VPN and not the one of the gateway, right?

Absolutely right, as long as the observer is not between the VM and the VPN server.
After passing through the VPN server, the IP will be one that is allocated by
the server.

Answer (score 0):

> From my understading in NAT mode the host acts like a router, so basically the host will navigate as usual while the guest will have created a tunnel from itself to the vpn server

Yes. The host sees as much as a regular router would see, nothing more or less.

(Note: If you are using VirtualBox, it does not use the host kernel's NAT or routing capabilities – the virtual 'router' is inside the VirtualBox VM monitor.)

> so if watching traffic from the gateway I'll see a clear traffic and a tunneled one, correct?

You will see packets that the VM actually sends over its Ethernet interface. This means that normally, you should only see the encrypted "outer" VPN packets (just as a real router would). There is no magic in virtual machines that would allow the host to see the "inner" tunnelled packets when it is not supposed to.

> And from an external server POV, if I connect via the VM, I should only see the IP of the VPN and not the one of the gateway, right?

Yes.